# Shamir Secret Sharing: Why cannot we recover polynomial's root if we have $t-1$ shares?

Tags: cryptanalysis, secret-sharing

Imagine we have $t-1$ shares in $(t,n)$ shamir secret sharing. So at least $t$ shares are needed.

Question: Why cannot we use $t-1$ shares to find a root of the polynomial and then recover the secret?

Comment: Related question: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19332/roots-of-polynomial-in-shamir-secret-sharing

Comment: @mikeazo   shall I remove this?

Comment: Definitely don't remove this. If that answers your question, let me know and we can mark this as a duplicate. I, however, don't think this is an exact duplicate and that we can leave it open.

Comment: @mikeazo If you had a time, could you have a look at the last question I put in the comment, please. I do appreciate for that.

Comment: My guess is that unless $(\beta, 0)$ is one of the shares, then the probability would be very small, something like $1/p$. But I'm not sure on that. That question in the comments would be a good question to ask on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I see you [already had asked it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410291/interpolating-a-polynomial-with-a-subset-of-interpolation-points) :)

Comment: @mikeazo I have had put some in different ways, but I got no clear answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a linear polynomial: $y=mx+b$. If I tell you that the point $(1,5)$ is on the line, can you tell me $m$ and $b$? No, because in fact there are infinitely many lines that pass through the point $(1,5)$. It takes 2 points to uniquely identify a line. In general it takes $t$ points to uniquely identify a degree $t-1$ polynomial. Furthermore, given $t-1$ points, there are infinitely many degree $t$ polynomials that have those $t-1$ points.

In practice, since we use **finite** fields in Shamir secret sharing, there are not infinitely many polynomials, but you get the point.

Now, as detailed [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/19334/706), you can potentially get roots of the polynomial from the shares. In particular, any share with a $0$ y value reveals a root. Even with all roots, however, you may not be able to correctly get the secret as there may be a common divisor among all coefficients that you could not recover with the roots. Assuming that is not the case, you would need all roots in order to reconstruct the polynomial to reveal the secret. So, for a degree $t-1$ polynomial (which has $t-1$ roots), all $t-1$ shares would have to have $0$ y values. The chances of that happening purely by chance is very small. If even one of the shares has a non-zero y value, then you have gained no information on the secret.

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. My question is " What is the probability that given $t-1$ shares, one can find a root of the polynomial?

Comment: @user13676 : $\:$ Does that mean "What is the probability that given t-1 shares, one's best guess at a root of the polynomial is correct?" or "What is the probability that given t-1 shares, there is a field element x such that those shares force x to be a root of the polynomial?"? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Yes, that what I meant.

Comment: @user13676 You are missing the point: with $t-1$ shares there are infinite polynomials, so all values are equally possible roots. In other words, with $t-1$ shares you still know nothing.

Comment: @user13676 Which is what you meant? The former or the latter?

Comment: Let me ask this. Imagine we have $\vec{x}=(x_1,...x_n)$  and two polynomials $P_1$ and $P_2$. Both's degree are smaller than $n-1$, but their product$ P_1\cdot P_2$ has a degree greater than $n-1$. $P_1$ has root $\beta$, where $\beta \leftarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$. for large prime $p$. We evaluate both polynomial at $(x_1,...,x_n)$. So we get $\vec{v}=(y_i,...,y_n)$ and $\vec{v}′=(y′_1,...,y′_n)$. We compute $\vec{v}′′=\vec{v}\cdot \vec{v}′$. The question is given $\vec{v}''$ and  $\vec{x}$ what is the probability that we interpolate a polynomial of degree at most $n−1$ and has root $\beta$?

Comment: @user13676 : $\:$ How is that related to cryptography? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer It is not, but it is related to polynomial interpolation. I thought you could help me with this, as you have related strong background.

Comment: Knowing all $t-1$ roots of polynomial of degree $t-1$, would still not be sufficient to deduce the constant term. The coefficient of degree $t-1$ will not show up knowing nothing but the roots, and this coefficient might have as many values as there are non-zero elements in the field.

Comment: @HenrickHellström I thought given the roots, you know the factorization of the polynomial, and hence, can reconstruct the polynomial. Take the example on [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialRoots.html), roots are $2, 1, -1$. Therefore the factorization is $(x-2)(x-1)(x+1)$ and the polynomial is $x^3-2x^2-x+2$, so the secret would be $2$. Maybe this doesn't translate or is not always the case?

Comment: @mikeazo You forgot about the highest order coefficient. $k(x-2)(x-1)(x+1)$ has the same roots for any value of $k$. And if you don't know $k$, you can't calculate the constant term.

Comment: @HenrickHellström I updated the answer to account for the case you mention. Thanks.

Comment: @mikeazo Hi, please read this regarding our yesterday discussion: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426924/how-to-compute-the-probability-distribution-of-w-r-1-cdot-ar-2-in-mathbbf/1427829#1427829

Answer (score 5):

Shamir Secret Sharing (SSS) is based on constructing a polynomial of degree $t-1$, whose independent term is the secret $S$. Each share is actually a point of the polynomial.

The security of SSS is based on the fact that, when one wants to interpolate a polynomial of degree $t-1$, one needs at least $t$ points of the polynomial. It can be seen graphically that trying to interpolate with less points (e.g., with $t-1$ points) is impossible since infinite polynomials can be drawn through those points. The [Wikipedia article for SSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing#Shamir.27s_secret-sharing_scheme) illustrates this very well.

In cryptographic applications you will not have "infinite" polynomials, but all the possible polynomials of degree $t$ for the given field. That means that knowing $t-1$ points is useless as all possible polynomials are equally plausible. This is called "perfect secrecy".

Answer (score 4):

[Shamir's $(t,n)$ secret sharing scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir's_Secret_Sharing) involves picking a random polynomial $p$ (over a finite field) of degree $t-1$, such that $p(0) = s$ is the secret value to be shared (this is easy to do, since $p(0)$ is just the constant term of the polynomial), and then evaluating the polynomial at $n$ distinct non-zero points $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$ to construct $n$ shares $(x_i, y_i)$, where $y_i = p(x_i)$.  Any $t$ of these shares can then be used to reconstruct the polynomial $p$ using [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial), and thus to reveal the secret $s$.

An immediate corollary of this definition is that, for any set of $t-1$ shares $(x_i, y_i$) and *any* possible secret $s'$, there is a (unique) polynomial $p'$ of order $t-1$ such that $p'(0) = s'$ and $p'(x_i) = y_i$.  (To find $p'$, just treat $(0, s')$ as an extra share and use Lagrange interpolation.)

Thus, given only $t-1$ shares, it's impossible to rule out *any* possible value of the secret, since there's a valid polynomial of degree $t-1$ that could yield that secret.  Whether or not you can learn anything about the roots of the polynomial is really irrelevant here.

**Ps.** It takes just a bit more work to complete the security proof by showing that, if the $t-1$ non-constant coefficients of $p$ have been chosen independently and uniformly at random, then the $y$-values of any set of $t-1$ shares are also uniformly distributed and independent of both each other and of the secret $s$, and thus that possession of $t-1$ shares does not yield even any probabilistic information about $s$.  Even this doesn't require any non-trivial probability theory — it's basically just a counting argument, showing that, for each value of $s$, the set of all possible $y$-values and the set of possible random coefficients are in one-to-one correspondence.  This is, however, the part that requires the underlying field to be finite — otherwise there is no uniform distribution over the field, and the whole argument falls apart.

Answer (score 3):

This is because $t$ shares uniquely defines the polynomial of degree $t-1$. $t-1$ shares still leaves $k$ possible and equally likely polynomials, for $k$ the size of the field, so the secret is information theoretically hidden.

Think of a degree 1 polynomial, essentially a line. If you know just one point on the line, you cannot say anything about the root (drawing this situation, should make that clear). But with one more point you get a unique line going through the first point, and can find all points on the line including the root.